# Colouring nodes based on attributes

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I'm trying to build a script that I can use to quickly visualize a network based on data I input into a node and edge `.csv` file respectively. I've been piecing together different bits of code and have the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

G = nx.Graph()
df_nodes = pd.read_csv('nodelist-Copy1.csv')
df_edges = pd.read_csv('edgelist-Copy1.csv')
```

My nodelist.csv file contains the following Columns: `Name`, `Role`, `Department`, `Gender`. I'm analyzing an org chart right now, but the Node attributes can change depending on the application

```
for index, row in df_nodes.iterrows():
    G.add_node(row['Name'], role=row['Role'], department=row['Department'], gender=row['Gender'])

for index, row in df_edges.iterrows():
    G.add_edges_from([(row['Source'], row['Target'])])

plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
options = {
    'edge_color': '#FFDEA2',
    'width': 1,
    'with_labels': True,
    'font_size': '7',
}

color_map = {'F':'#f09494', 'M':'#eebcbc'} 
colors = [color_map[G.nodes[node]['gender']] for node in G]

nx.draw(G, node_colors = colors, pos=nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.25, iterations=50), **options)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#555555") 
plt.show()
```

Not too sure how to troubleshoot this. What I hope to accomplish is that the nodes are coloured differently based on their attribute, in this instance their gender. When I execute this code now, I don't have errors, but the Node colours do not change

Answer (score 1):

I believe the attribute your are trying to access on your graph is `nodes` not `node` and that is what is causing the error.  Instead, try this:

```
colors = [color_map[G.nodes[node]['gender']] for node in G]
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right that did take care of the attribute error, now the script recognizes the gender type, `F` or `M`, but I have a key error, I expected the script to assign a color value to Fs and Ms at this point